# Is It Possible to Have a Cognos Custom Authentication Provider Use JAXWS?

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client, cognos

I am working on creating a CAM (custom authentication module/provider) for Cognos 10.

Various encrypted information is passed into the provider from the query string.  The Namespace's authentication process is then designed to talk to a web service in order to validate the encrypted information wasn't tampered with and to make sure the user's "session" in the authenticating application hasn't expired.

The authenticating application uses .NET and has the web service exposed for use with SOAP requests (1.1 and 1.2, I believe).  I pointed wsimport at the wsdl and generated a set of classes that works when I build a standard Java console app and pass along debug values.

When I add this code into my Namespace class and attempt the request to the web service I am getting this error from Cognos:

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl (initialization failure)

I thought Cognos 10 was using JDK 1.6.  I am developing my CAM code in 1.6 (64bit JDK).  I should have 64bit Cognos running but I do not know if it is using a 32bit JDK.  Could a possible disparity in 32bit vs. 64bit be causing the issue?

Any clue as to why the generated classes from wsimport (JAXWS) won't work in Cognos?  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to mark this as answered but I'll put the caveat that I haven't tested this.

After dealing with trying to get 3rd party libraries to work with my CAP/CAM I figured that the reason JAXWS was not working correctly because Cognos didn't have that included in its Java distribution.

I got a similar error to the above when trying to use Microsoft's JDBC implementation to talk to a SQL server for namespace searches.  This leads me to believe that the same situation exists with JAXWS.

I looked around for the jar file that should contain the classes that would need to be there.  I didn't see any jar file that was named the same as what I have for 1.6.  Unless it truly isn't supported in Cognos I think including the jar file for JAXWS in the WEB-INF/lib folder will allow webservice communications using JAXWS.